# Does perfectly inelastic collision conserve energy if given external energies are negligble?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, momentum

If in the question given perfectly inelastic collision and assuming heat and sound energy are negligible then Mechanical energy is conserved opposite to the general law?

Answer (score 0):

> Does perfectly inelastic collision conserve energy if given external energies are negligble ?

Energy across the whole system and environment is *always* conserved. If the *kinetic* energy of the system is the same before and after the collision then the collision is, by definition, elastic and not inelastic.